# How to locate elements through Selenium and Xpath

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath, web-scraping, webdriverwait

So I am trying to scrape some information from a website, and when I try to get element by xpath I am getting an error "Unable to locate element" when the path that I provide is copied directly from the inspection tool. I tried a couple of things but it did not work, so I told my self I was going to try an easier path (TEST) but still don't work. Is it possible that the website does not show all the html code when inspecting?

Here is the code, with the website and the xpath that I tried.

```
URL_TRADER = 'https://www.tipranks.com/analysts/joseph-foresi?benchmark=none&period=yearly'

TEST = 'html/body/div[@id="app"]/div[@class="logged-out free"]/div[@class="client-components-app-app__wrapper undefined undefined"]'#/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/section/main/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/span'

X_PATH = '//*[@id="app"]/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/section/main/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/span'
```

The main function is:

```
def trader_table():

  # Loading Chrome and getting to the website
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
  driver.get(URL_TRADER)
  driver.implicitly_wait(10)
  text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(X_PATH).get_attribute('innerHTML')
  
  return text
```

Comment: can you specify element that you want xpath

Comment: Can you provide the html code of the exact element you are trying to reach

Answer (score 1):

I added a wait condition and used a css selector combination instead but this is the same as your xpath I think

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

url = 'https://www.tipranks.com/analysts/joseph-foresi?benchmark=none&period=yearly'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(url)
data =  WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".client-components-experts-infoTable-expertTable__table .client-components-experts-infoTable-expertTable__dataRow td:nth-child(3)"))).get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(data)
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking after `price` Here you go.

```
from selenium import webdriver
URL_TRADER = 'https://www.tipranks.com/analysts/joseph-foresi?benchmark=none&period=yearly'

TEST = 'html/body/div[@id="app"]/div[@class="logged-out free"]/div[@class="client-components-app-app__wrapper undefined undefined"]'#/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/section/main/table/tbody/tr[3]/td[3]/div/div/div/div[1]/span'

X_PATH = "//div[@class='client-components-experts-infoTable-expertTable__isBuy']/div/span"

def trader_table():
 driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
 driver.get(URL_TRADER)
 driver.implicitly_wait(10)
 text = driver.find_element_by_xpath(X_PATH).get_attribute('innerHTML')
 print(text)
 return text
```

**Edited for All rows**

```
    from selenium import webdriver
    URL_TRADER = 'https://www.tipranks.com/analysts/joseph-foresi?benchmark=none&period=yearly'

    X_PATH = "//div[@class='client-components-experts-infoTable-expertTable__isBuy']/div/span"


    def trader_table():
     driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/usr/local/bin/chromedriver')
     driver.get(URL_TRADER)
     driver.implicitly_wait(10)
     list_ele= driver.find_elements_by_xpath(X_PATH)
     price_list = []
     for ele in list_ele:
         print(ele.text)
         price_list.append(ele.text)

     return price_list

list=trader_table()
print(list)
```

Comment: Hey, Thank you very much! do you have an idea why is the xpath from the inspect tool was giving a "wrong" path?

Comment: and how I should modify the X_PATH that you provide me to get the other values. I tried to use text() instead of get_attribute('innerHTML') but it does not work

Comment: @babas: are you looking after price values of all rows?

Comment: use `driver.find_element_by_xpath(X_PATH).text` it is printed me the price.

Comment: @Babas : Check my updated code for all rows.I have taken a list to store all the value.

Answer (score 1):

You have provided all the necessary details required to construct an answer but you didn't explicitly mention which *element you were trying to get*.

However, the commented out *xpath* within `TEST` gives us a hint you were after the **Price Target** and to extract the *text* within those elements as the elements are [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) enabled elements, you need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the `visibility_of_all_elements_located()` and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
  options.add_argument('start-maximized')
  options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')
  driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\WebDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  driver.get("https://www.tipranks.com/analysts/joseph-foresi?benchmark=none&period=yearly")
  print([element.get_attribute('innerHTML') for element in WebDriverWait(driver,10).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='client-components-experts-infoTable-expertTable__isBuy']//span")))])
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  ['$14.00', '$110.00', '$237.00', '$36.00', '$150.00', '$71.00', '$188.00', '$91.00', '$101.00', '$110.00']
  ```

Comment: Great answer and sorry If I wasn't totally clear about what was my goal.

Answer (score 0):

```js
from selenium import webdriver
import time

driver = webdriver.Chrome("your webdriver location")
driver.get("https://www.tipranks.com/analysts/joseph-foresi?benchmark=none&period=yearly")
time.sleep(10)
y = driver.find_element_by_id('app').get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(y)
```

prints full inner html